# Need help understanding why proof of continuity from below is wrong

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In a probability theory course I'm following along with, continuity from below is stated as:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $A_1,A_2,\cdot\cdot\cdot$
> $\subset \mathcal{F}$. If  $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3 \subset$
> $\cdot\cdot\cdot$ , then $$ \mu\bigg(\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1} A_i \bigg) = \lim_{i \to \infty} \mu(A_i)$$

Now, my math background is not strong, so I'm not sure why what I have would be wrong so I'm hoping someone can point it out to me.

What I got for proving continuity from below was that for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$:

\begin{align}
&\bigcup^{n}_{i=1} A_i = A_n \\
\implies & \mu\bigg(\bigcup^{n}_{i=1} A_i \bigg) = \mu(A_n) \\
 \lim_{n \to \infty} & \mu\bigg(\bigcup^{n}_{i=1} A_i \bigg) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n) \\
& \mu\bigg(\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1} A_i \bigg) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)
\end{align}

Most proofs I've seen use countable additivity, so I'm assuming mine is wrong since it's too simple in comparison.

Comment: The claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\cup_{1}^{n}A_i) = \mu(\lim_{n\to\infty}\cup_1^nA_i)$ which you use in the last step is *precisely* what you are trying to prove. So your argument is circular: you are assuming your conclusion holds,and using that assumption to show it holds.

Comment: $\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i$ is just a more complicated way of writing $A_n$. In simplified notation, this is your argument: $$A_n=A_n$$ $$\implies\mu(A_n)=\mu(A_n)$$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$$ $$\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for taking the time to respond. I'm still confused though. I thought $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ so we get $\lim_{n \to \infty} 
 \mu\big(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i \big) = \mu\big(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\big)$. Or is that wrong for the same reason that a function $f(x)$ might have $f(a)=L$, but $\lim_{x \to 
a} f(x) \neq L$ necessarily? (I may also be confusing the definition of infinite sums and assuming that it's similar for infinite unions)

Comment: @user14111 Rofl, that does look pretty funny. Sorry if this is a silly question, but isn't that how some proofs go? You replace something with its definition or write it out another way to show what is required? I'm still confused why that would make it wrong.

Comment: Regarding the comment in reply to Arturo: Why do you believe $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ and $\mu$ commute?  You argue as if that is obvious.  But why is it?  The method you mention (countable additivity) comes at this the other way round, converting $\mu(\text{disjoint union})$ into $\sum \mu(\dots)$, so you can rub the limit and the sum together (i.e., transform the inside of the limit to put something familiar immediately in the limit, instead of the unfamiliar $\mu$).